# 2 separate Profile2 Views (one faculty, one staff)

Tags: views, users

I've been able to create a view with the profile2 module (with custom forms)that renders all users on a view. How can I create a separate category of users, say 'faculty' and 'students' and have a view for each? So the faculty view would only show users labeled as faculty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a field "user type" to the current profile and then add a views filter or views "contextual filter" to only show one type at a time. You may need to add a "relationship" on the profile2.

Alternatively, profile2 lets you specify different types of profiles. So you could make a 'faculty' profile and a 'students' profile.

It really depends on what would work best in your setup.

Comment: If I do this via profile2, how do I configure the view to only show faculty then? Is there a tutorial you can point me to? Much appreciated!

Comment: [This tutorial](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-creating-membership-directory-views-and-profile-2) looks pretty good